# Making specific columns in a text file into a list

Tags: python, file-io

I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
TITPLE="SurfaceData"
VARIABLES="X", "Y", "Z", "Cutoff Rigidity", "Injected Particle Number"
ZONE N=30, E=25, DATAPACKING=POINT, ZONETYPE=FEQUADRILATERAL
0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 6.371000e+06  4.843809e-01  2.001000e+03
0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 6.371000e+06  4.635282e-01  2.022500e+03
0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 6.371000e+06  1.158746e+00  1.984500e+03
0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 6.371000e+06  1.153130e+00  1.960500e+03
0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 6.371000e+06  4.873921e-01  1.986500e+03
1 2 7 6
2 3 8 7
3 4 9 8
4 5 10 9
```

In python 3, I would like to convert the first 3 columns of data into 3 separate lists and ignore all of the other columns and data in the file. In other words, I would like to convert the following three columns into three lists:

```
0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 6.371000e+06
0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 6.371000e+06 
0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 6.371000e+06  
0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 6.371000e+06  
0.000000e+00 0.000000e+00 6.371000e+06
```

where each column represents a separate list. I have seen ways to do this when there is no other data in the file, but I cannot find a way to ignore the text above the data and the set of integers below that data. Does anyone have any solutions?

Comment: Why don't you read the file, skip the first 3 lines, read the rest of the lines, split each at whitespace into a list, and keep the first 3 values from the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `pandas`, it also fixes the scientific notation:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=None, skiprows=3, skipfooter=4, engine='python')
```

Output `df`:

|  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 6371000.0 | 0.4843809 | 2001.0 |
| 1 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 6371000.0 | 0.4635282 | 2022.5 |
| 2 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 6371000.0 | 1.1587459999999998 | 1984.5 |
| 3 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 6371000.0 | 1.15313 | 1960.5 |
| 4 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 6371000.0 | 0.48739209999999994 | 1986.5 |

To keep only the first three columns: `df = df[[0,1,2]]`

To convert a column to a list: `df[0].tolist()`